# Calculating a weighted average while excluding certain rows conditional on a string

Tags: r, mean

I have a matrix containing values and an ID specific to each row. I'm trying to calculate the simple mean of these values but would like to manually exclude some of the values depending on its ID.

Say I have the following matrix:

```
library(stringi)

set.seed(20)

mat <- cbind.data.frame(id = stri_rand_strings(6, 3, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]") ,
             number = runif(6, min=0, max=100) )
```

giving

```
   id    number
1 slH 28.926236
2 Wxy 81.945649
3 54K 49.196770
4 Mik  3.025649
5 0kB 44.023153
6 SJ6  7.728510
```

the mean would be: `mean(mat$number )` giving `35.80766`.

I would like to repeat that calculation but be able to manually choose which variables to exclude. For instance, if I wanted to exclude: `slH` and `54K` I could try manually removing those rows:

```
mean(mat$number[-c(1 , 3)] ,)
```

but this could be problematic if the matrix and ID's to be ignored are very large (easy to make mistakes). Is there a way to manually give the values to exclude?

Comment: `no <- mat$id %in% c("slH", "54K")`. Then, `mean(mat$number[!no])`.

Comment: Just a comment - you don't have a matrix, you have a data frame. A matrix has only one data type, but you have different data types in different columns.

Comment: @Thomas: yes that's true!

Comment: @Rui: thank you for that syntax! I don't know how to accept your answer and close the question

Comment: That is not an answer, it's a comment. So, leave it be, don't worry. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)


set.seed(20)

df1 <- tibble(id = stri_rand_strings(6, 3, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]"),
              number = runif(6, min = 0, max = 100))
df1
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   id    number
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 slH    28.9 
#> 2 Wxy    81.9 
#> 3 54K    49.2 
#> 4 Mik     3.03
#> 5 0kB    44.0 
#> 6 SJ6     7.73

df1 %>%
  filter(! id %in% c("slH", "54K")) %>%
  summarise(number = mean(number))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   number
#>    <dbl>
#> 1   34.2
```